# Copy 1 files to 100 folders in the same directory

Tags: linux, bash

i need to copy 1 file ( index.php ) 
/home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder1/index.php

into 100 folders into the same directory  (all folders into this directory)
/home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder2/

in this example,directory folder2 have 100 folders

How can i do this with 1 command shell ?

Thanks for help

Comment: how about `find /home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder2/ -maxdepth=1 -type d -exec cp /home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder1/index.php {}/ \;`?

Comment: You don't want that.. you should rather create symlinks to *one* real index.php.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find /path/to/directory/* -type d  -exec cp /path/to/file.txt {} \;
```

Example:

```
find /home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder2/* -type d  -exec cp /home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder1/index.php {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use xargs

```
ls -d */ | xargs cp <path to single file>
```

In your case,

```
cd /home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder2/
ls -d */ | xargs cp /home/name/domains/domainname.com/public_html/folder1/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in heute/z/*/ ; do cp a.mp4 "$f"; done
```

While you often see useless trailing slashes in command, here, in the for loop, it is essential to prevent overriding of simple files in heute/z/ and to just take dirs as params.

control:

```
find heute/z/ -name a.mp4 
heute/z/c/a.mp4
heute/z/b/a.mp4
```

This works with symbolic links too, if you happen to be impressed by the suggestion to use such.